# Android browser insert hyphen after 8 digit

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails

When i copy-paste password from email in android phone i can't login my site.

Console log have hidden characters after paste password
Example password in email: 5038000646

But in log it is 50380006­46 (between 6 and 46 hidden character "-")
how fix it?

```
a.split("").each { |c| p c.ord }
53
48
51
56
48
48
48
54
173
52
54
 => ["5", "0", "3", "8", "0", "0", "0", "6", "­", "4", "6"]
```

field to password use angular model

Comment: 173 - ascii code hidden char

Answer (score 0):

Just remove character with 173 ascii code from string. User can't use it in password.